# Getting multiple stickers(CSGO) using Steam Web API in PHP

Tags: php, steam, inventory

So i have been having troubles with seeing if a user has more than one of the same sticker in their inventory using the Steam Web API.

`http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198188713228/inventory/json/730/2`

My current code works perfectly fine when displaying any other item that has an amount greater than one, but when it comes to displaying a sticker it will only display one on the site.

Here is my code:

```
            $Steam_inv= file_get_contents($urls[2]);
            $Steam_Json = json_decode($Steam_inv, true);

            echo "User is logged in (steamID: $matches[1])\n";


            //var_dump($Steam_Json['rgDescriptions']['1989271297_0']['market_name']);
            $TotalItems = 0;

            foreach ($Steam_Json['rgDescriptions'] as $item){
                $TotalItems++;
                $itemBD = json_encode($item);
                $itemAD = json_decode($itemBD, true);

                $result = json_encode($itemAD['market_name']);
                $result = str_replace('"', " ", json_encode($itemAD['market_name']));
                $result = str_replace('Factory New', "FN", $result);
                $result = str_replace('Minimal Wear', "MW", $result);
                $result = str_replace('Field-Tested', "FT", $result);
                $result = str_replace('Well-Worn', "WW", $result);
                $result = str_replace('Battle-Scarred', "BS", $result);
                $result = str_replace('\u2122', " ", $result);
                $result = str_replace('\u2605', " ", $result);                  

                $WepType = json_encode($itemAD['tags'][0]['internal_name']);
                $WepType = str_replace('"', "", $WepType);


                    if($WepType != "CSGO_Type_WeaponCase" && $WepType != "CSGO_Type_Knife")
                    {
                    $colors = json_encode($itemAD['tags'][4]['color']);
                    $colors = str_replace('"', "", $colors);
                    }
                    elseif ($WepType == "CSGO_Type_Knife"){
                        $colors = "FFD700";
                        $result = "★" . $result;
                    }


                $pics = json_encode($itemAD['classid']);
                $pics = str_replace('"', "", $pics);
                echo "<p style='color:#$colors;position:relative;left:50%;'>" . $result . "</p>" . "<img class='Guns' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/$pics'></img>";
            }
            echo $TotalItems;
```

Sorry if its sloppy, im really new to PHP.

Comment: Try to do `print_r` on each `$item` and see if it is working as spected, before all that code insde loop

Comment: doing this, it displays only one of each sticker in the data when you (CTRL + F "[market_name] => sticker"), and yes everything else looks fine from what i can see.

Comment: Can you re explain this: "My current code works perfectly fine when displaying any other item that has an amount greater than one, but when it comes to displaying a sticker it will only display one on the site". For what I understand, your problem is that when you have to display one sticker, what is the problem ? When displaying multiple stickers ? I am running your code and works as spected

Comment: Well as you can see, every other items in the players inventory are being displayed perfectly fine, but he also has more than one of the same sticker and more than one of the same sticker is not being recognized or displaying on the website. For example the Crown foil sticker

Comment: In the JSON recived I only see one :S Can you tell me in which lines of the JSON are the other crowns ?

Comment: Welp thats where im bamboozled, in the players inventory he has more than 1 but in the JSON it only shows 1, i tried looking at other values that could possibly show more than 1 but i couldnt find any.

Comment: I know steam, I am a 10 years steam user, but I have never used his API, so there must be something there that gives you the amount of items the player has